# Cant register my website as a webhook for Configuring webhook notifications from google

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I was hoping to implement a simple XMPP server in Java and for that I was trying to add my website as a webhook and I verified my website owner ship using html upload method and then the following error message is shown by Google  "Error You do not have access to the following domain: www.jlonics.com".My domain is  www.jlonics.com .I searched for long and couldn't get an answer please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did it by just by installing a certificate to my server and thus making it HTTPS insted of HTTP.Google accepts only HTTPS as webhooks.